# Export to Excel from ASP.NET

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
I have a webpage with one textbox (search) and many buttons. Each buttons is for different queries (using `page.aspx.vb` to the code for each buttons) that are pulling from SQL Server using stored procedures. The textbox is the search field for any of the queries that the user click on. There is also an ‘Export to Excel’ button.

The `page.aspx` code does not have `BoundField` in the markup, just a `GridView`. Because each of the queries headings different and is pulling data from different tables.

Could someone tell me how to get the code for export to Excel without the `BoundField` is need in `page.aspx`?

This is what I have. The only thing I cane't get it to work, is the Export to Excel.
```

This is the html page

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ExportWithOutBoundField.aspx.vb"   Inherits="zTestExport_ExportWithOutBoundField" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
  <p>
  Export to Excel
  </p>
  <p>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaterialNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="btnGetData" runat="server" Text="GetData"/>
  </p>  
  <p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Excel"/>
  </p>
  <p><asp:Label ID="lblMaterialCount" runat="server" Text="(0: Row Count)"></asp:Label></p>
  <p>     <asp:GridView ID="ExportToExcel" runat="server"></asp:GridView></p>
    </div>
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is the code behind that pull data from Stored Procedures in the SQL Server and put the data in GridView

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.DataSet
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class zTestExport_ExportWithOutBoundField
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub btnGetData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGetData.Click
        Dim gv As DataSet
        Dim STREWEB2connection As SqlConnection
        Dim ATOMSserver As SqlDataAdapter
        'Create a connection to the SQL Server.
        STREWEB2connection = New SqlConnection("")
        'Create a DataAdapter, and then provide the name of the stored procedure.
        ATOMSserver = New SqlDataAdapter("GetCATO", STREWEB2connection)
        'Set the command type as StoredProcedure.
        ATOMSserver.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        'Create and add a parameter to Parameters collection for the stored procedure.
        ATOMSserver.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Material", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40))
        'Assign the search value to the parameter.
        ATOMSserver.SelectCommand.Parameters("@Material").Value = Trim(txtMaterialNumber.Text)
        'Create and add an output parameter to Parameters collection. 
        ATOMSserver.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@RowCount", SqlDbType.Int, 4))
        'Set the direction for the parameter. This parameter returns the Rows returned.
        ATOMSserver.SelectCommand.Parameters("@RowCount").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        gv = New DataSet() 'Create a new DataSet to hold the records.
        ATOMSserver.Fill(gv, "GetCATO") 'Fill the DataSet with the rows returned.
        'Get the number of rows returned, and then assign it to the Label control.
        'lblRowCount.Text = DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count().ToString() & " Rows Found!"
        lblMaterialCount.Text = ATOMSserver.SelectCommand.Parameters(1).Value & " Rows Found! (Material)"
        'Set the data source for the DataGrid as the DataSet that holds the rows.
        ExportToExcel.DataSource = gv.Tables("GetCATO").DefaultView
        'Bind the DataSet to the DataGrid. 
        'NOTE: If you do not call this method, the DataGrid is not displayed!
        ExportToExcel.DataBind()
        ATOMSserver.Dispose() 'Dispose of the DataAdapter.
        STREWEB2connection.Close() 'Close the connection.
    End Sub
```

I can't get this part to work. Is the one that I need to export into Excel

```
    Protected Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
        Dim ad As New DataSet()
        Dim dt As DataTable
        'dt = ad.Read()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim attachment As String = "attachment; filename=3DUSurvey.xls"
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Dim tab As String = ""
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName)
            tab = vbTab
        Next
        Response.Write(vbLf)
        Dim i As Integer
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            tab = ""
            For i = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                Response.Write(tab & dr(i).ToString())
                tab = vbTab
            Next
            Response.Write(vbLf)
        Next
        Response.[End]()
        'export to excel
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `BoundField` and `GridView` don't sound like **ASP Classic** - that sounds like `ASP.NET` only! Removing tag ....

Comment: Sorry. Texting from phone. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The code for export to excel does not depend on whether you have bound field or not. You can just render the gridview to excel. You can use the following code in the export to excel button click event.

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "");
string exportFileName = "excelfilename.xls";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + exportFileName + "\"");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
GridView gridView;
gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
//Get data from stored procedure based on the creteria
gridView.DataSource = dataSource //change this;
gridView.DataBind();
gridView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
Response.End();
```

Comment: Hi Kiran. Many thank for your help. Have try that. Not sure where I gone wrong in term of bugs I get from running the code you give me. For example my GridView is "GrdUsers". The button goes to the codebehind to run the procedures that put the data in "GrdUsers". Then the export button if click will then export the data in "GrdUsers" to Excel. Hope that help to what I'm still looking for.

Comment: In the export button click event you need to add the above code. Here you need to bind the grid GrdUsers, by running the procedures. After binding the grid, you need to render the control to htmlwriter which actually flushes the data to excel. Let me know what is not working, if you have further problems

Comment: Hi Kiran, Error come up. For example. 'String' is a class type and cannot be used as an Expression. Also what do I change the dataSource to?

Comment: Hi Kiran, Have use Javascript. Tks for your help. Now I must go and search how to format the data using javasript before exporting to Excel. Cheers